# VS Code: Pester tests not showing in test explorer

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, pester

My VS code test explorer tab is always empty for any Powershell Pester tests. I have the latest Powershell Extension installed (v2022.8.5). It looks like test discovering does not work, but I can run/debug single `describe` blocks nicely.

Note: I tried installing the Pester Test Extension [1], but it disables the single test run/debug option coming with Pester 5 [2].

[1] https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pspester.pester-test

[2] https://pester.dev/docs/usage/vscode